# XMLEncoder skipping ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, instantiationexception, xmlencoder

I've a JButton I've encoded with XMLEncoder, and all was well for me, until I tried adding an ActionListener. Now, I get this message

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Temp$1
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: XMLEncoder: discarding statement JButton.addActionListener(Temp$1);
Continuing ...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how it can be prevented?

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box `XMLEncoder` can only cope with custom classes that are Java Beans, in particular the class must have a no-argument constructor. Anonymous inner classes such as your `Test$1` don't have a no-argument constructor at the bytecode level because the compiler inserts an invisible argument at the start of the constructors' parameter lists to pass in a reference to the "containing instance" of the class that enclosed the inner class.

The [java.beans package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html#package_description) makes exactly this point, and suggests using [java.beans.EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html) instead of inner classes for listeners.